# ASP.NET MVC Azure Web Role and Temp folder Size

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, azure

I am running into size limitations of temp folder of an Asp.Net MVC app that's deployed on Azure.
Specifically, when the users upload the file that's large, say 100mb or more as the file is uploaded it exhausts the temp folder and soon the app disconnects. Is there a way of specifying a custom temp folder for an Asp.Net MVC Web role via RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource type a thing?

Comment: In case anyone still has this issue. [How to increase the size of the Windows Azure Web Role ASP.NET Temporary Folder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/07/18/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-windows-azure-web-role-asp-net-temporary-folder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an advanced client side uploading engine like http://www.plupload.com/ that supports uploading in chunks? If you combine that with Azure blob storage you will have a scalable solution and avoid the temp file problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Windows Azure Training Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse.aspx): No, that is not possible (cf. the presentation "ASP.NET in Windows Azure.pptx" that is part of the training kit)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define and add a local storage resource to you web role:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-local-storage-resources/

You can then use the standard File.IO functions to access this resource, or you can redirect the TEMP folder to it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/07/18/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-windows-azure-web-role-asp-net-temporary-folder.aspx